# Difference between Strategy Pattern and State Pattern using example

Tags: design-patterns, strategy-pattern, state-pattern

Although there are many questions over the same topic, none of them cleared my confusion completely. So I am attempting to put an example and its solution with both patterns.

Please tell me if I am doing it correctly or what wrong I am doing.

Classes:

- **BeforeCondition**: defines voltage level, fuel quantity, rotator belt condition
- **Baker**: a machine which bakes cookies
- **LowSpeedBaker, HighSpeedBaker, MediumSpeedBaker**: various implementations or rather states of Baker.
- **BakerStateFactory**: it accepts BeforeCondtion and returns one of the state of Baker.

**Implementation 1**:

Client creates **BeforeCondition** and get appropriate baker from **BakerStateFactory**. Now it calls bake() of baker.

**Implementation 2**:

Client doesn't bother about how machine works. It just passes BeforeCondition to the Baker machine. Baker machine itself decides its state on the basis of BeforeCondition.

**Conclusion**

First implementation lets client decide the state or what implementation has to be injected. It doesn't bother whether machine can actually work on that condition or not. This is strategy pattern.

In second implementation, machine it self can decide its state and work accordingly. It is also free to change its state between the process, if it requires. This is state pattern.

Comment: I would answer the question: What is defined in my project? If you do not know that, you cannot really decide which pattern is better in your case. We create software for customers to solve their problems, so we need to know what the problems actually are :)

Comment: I don't wanna compare which pattern is better or suites to this condition. But trying to understand distinction between both by their implementation.

Comment: So I think you have answered your question pretty well. In your case Strategy gives more control to class user, where state gives more self control for your class.

Comment: ohk so my distinction is correct. thanks

Comment: As I think your conclusion is still a bit unclear, I wrote you a little story ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example scene:

You want to use the strategy pattern, when you use only one algorithm per baking process. There are many algorithms, but for each baking process you use only one of them. In this case your strategies for the Baker might be *CookieProcess*, *PizzaProcess*, ... To bake a pizza you configure the *Baker* to use the *PizzaProcess*. Then you pass the ingredients to the *bake()* method and the Pizza is sent to your mailbox. Go with this, because thinking about a return type here might be confusing and you end up fighting the factory pattern, too. When you configure the *Baker* to use *CookieProcess* the *Baker* bakes them and sends half of them downtown to your granny's mailbox.

So there are two different strategies here:

- bake at 220 Celsius and send to your mailbox,
- bake at 180 Celsius and send to you and your granny

When you want to model the baking process in greater detail you will use the state pattern. In this case your states might be *BakerOff*, *BakerPreheating*, *BakerPreheatingDone*, *BakerHeating*, *BakerCooldown*. When you start to prepare the chocolate chip cookies for the stupid conference on Friday, the *Baker* is in state *BakerOff*. Sleepy as you are, you try to put the cookies in and this fails with an exception saying **only bad confectioners bake their cookies without pre-heating**. So you call the enable() method of the Baker. The internal state changes to *BakerPreheating* and after some time to *BakerPreheatingDone*. At this state transition a callback might be invoked, e.g. the huge built in BakerBell. This reminds you to actually put in the cookies and start the *BakerHeating* phase ...

So here we bake cookies for granny only, but in a detailed fassion with many states.
Note that you can bake cookies only with this *Baker*, since you have only the one baking algorithm in there.

For an advanced *Baker* you might combine the patterns. Then you can Bake pizza and cookies in the same *Baker* with fancy pre-heating stuff! Of course it is possible to skip the preheating phase when the *Baker* is configured for the *PizzaProcess*.

You end up with a baker which can use different strategies (Pizza, Cookies). Each of them uses some states to complete. The strategie however decides which states might be skipped or exchanged. (Maybe the strategy has a method *isPreheatingForced()*)